# How to hash auto increments in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there a way to make mysql hash the auto increment values for its tables? 
For example with md5?

```
    id - name
    1  - New York  
    2  - Chicago   
    3  - Sydney    
    4  - Berlin
```

what I'm trying to get

```
    id - name 
    c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b - New York  
    c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c - Chicago   
    eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3 - Sydney    
    a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c - Berlin
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I think I need to clarify the question a little more, what im trying to do is not Call the ID's but Insert them. In the moment the ID column is an int field which I will change to varchar.

I want to save the identifiers as Hashed in the DB not call them with mysql SELECT. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really need this, for some reason, you can achieve it with a help of a separate table for sequencing and a `BEFORE` trigger

Table schemas:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1_seq
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE table1
(id VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, name VARCHAR(32));
```

The trigger

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bi_table1
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1_seq () VALUES ();
  SET NEW.id = MD5(LAST_INSERT_ID());
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now you can insert rows into your `table1` table

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (`name`) VALUES ('New York'),('Chicago'),('Sydney'),('Berlin');
```

or select

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = MD5(2);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de33b/1)** demo

Comment: can you please check the fiddle demo. its not showing anything

Comment: @KapilPaul it's an issue on sqlfiddle side

Answer (score 3):

All the answers above lack a good understanding of the need to use hashed id's.

Hashing the auto increment id violates the whole concept.
The concept you want to reach is that the next id will be unpredictable from the previous.

In the idea of hashing the id the next id of the md5( 1 ) is the md5( 2 ).

If you use the names that helps.

It would be best to create the hash from several fields.
The fields together should be unique to create a unique hash.

Answer (score 1):

**`MySQL`** Docs say..

> Functions cannot be added as COLUMN DEFAULTS - except for now() that
>   is internally represented as a synonym of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

A best bet would be to do this...

```
UPDATE yourtablename SET id=MD5(id) WHERE 1=1;
```

or to run a **`TRIGGER`**

Something like ... (*Not 100% correct... just giving you an idea*)

```
CREATE TRIGGER generateMD5forID BEFORE INSERT ON `yourtablename` FOR EACH ROW SET id = MD5(id);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in a BEFORE trigger, the id column has not been given an auto-increment value. But it's too late to change it in an AFTER trigger. Also you can't make a VARCHAR column auto-incrementing, it has to be one of the integer types. But if it's an integer, you can't store a string of hex digits in it.

Comment: Thanks Bill. You are right. That's why i put that statement inside the italics., as i was not sure if that would really work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i did not understand the question, but this is my opinion:

I think you try to create a hash table. So insert id field as hash of your data (md5(name)).

But if not, use a table trigger to generate field hash after insert.

Comment: I like the idea of using unique fields for the identifier like.. md5(name) but that means i need to redesign the whole programm and that would cost sadly too much time. I like the trigger idea but don't have that much experience with it. I will experiment with it later on and try to combine that with my own soluntion posted here if such thing is possible.. but all in all thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Answers here brought up an Idea in me.. I think that will work as the best solution for now.. but if there is someone who knows an easier way I'm glad to hear it.

**Solution:**

Create a new table with an auto increment field like id or count, which you will always increment first and use the last ID out of that table to hash it for the primary field of your other table.